# local variable referenced before assignment error on my code

Tags: python

the program i am making is a dice game that allows two users roll 2 6-sided dice each. But I am unsure of how to correctly insert it so the score variables become global variables as it is not working. player one scores are under the variable p1score and player 2's scores are stored under the variable p2score.

```
def roundtwo():
    p1r2 = input("Player 1 are you ready for round 2 type y = yes n= no: ")
    if p1r2 == 'y' or p1r2 == 'Y':
        p1dice1 = random.randint(min,max)
        p1dice2 = random.randint(min,max)
        print("The value of dice 1 is:", p1dice1)
        print("The value of dice 2 is:", p1dice2)
        if (p1dice1 % 2) == 0 :
            p1score = p1score + p1dice1 + p1dice2
            p1score = p1score + 10
            print("The results for Player 1 in round 2 is: ", p1score)
        elif (p1dice2 % 2) == 0:
            p1score = p1score + p1dice1 + p1dice2
            p1score = p1score + 10
            print("The results for Player 1 in round 2 is: ", p1score)
        elif (p1dice1 % 2) == 0 and (p1dice2 % 2) == 0:
            p1score = p1score + p1dice1 + p1dice2
            p1score = p1score + 20
            print("The results for Player 1 in round 2 is: ", p1score)
        else:
            p1score = p1score + p1dice1 + p1dice2
            print("The results of Player 1 in round 2 is: ", p1score)
    else:
        user()
```

I need it to calculate the points for round 2 for both players. so after round one if player 1 gets 3 and then in round 2 gets 14, the score for player one in round one should be 17.

Comment: Your error code should have more information than you provided, can you copy-paste the whole thing here?

Answer (score 0):

In this line here: `p1score = p1score + p1dice1 + p1dice2`  have you already set `p1score` to 0? If not then this line could give you a local variable referenced before assignment error